# ¿Qué formula puedo usar para obtener un valor según una columna? Pensé en BDEXTRAER

Tags: excel

Estoy intentando asociar el contenido de la columna E, que está en otra pestaña, y llenar con ese contenido la columna B, según el número de Ticket. Es decir, hacer coincidir la Solución al Número de ticket, según el orden de tickets ubicado en la Columna A.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que espero obtener, es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa la función [`buscarv`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/función-buscarv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Lo intenté hacer, pero no logro hacer mucho más allá de verificar que encuentre valores para cada uno de los tickets. Usando las imágenes lo haría así: =VLOOKUP(A3,D$3:D$7,1,FALSE).

Comment: @Sal podrías apoyarme con algo más de orientación. Me parece que estoy malentendiendo la función.

Comment: El rango es de renglones fijos y debe incluir la columna de valores. La columna del valor a obtener es la segunda del rango.

Comment: Busca información sobre las funciones INDICE y COINCIDIR, a ver si es lo que necesitas. Aquí hay bastante info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con BUSCARV:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> [Función
> BUSCARV](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-buscarv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Mi formula es:

```
=BUSCARV(A2;$E$2:$F$6;2;FALSO)
```

En mi ejemplo todo está aplicado en una hoja, pero se puede aplicar en varias. Y recuerda bloquear la referencia donde estás mirando (fíjate en mi fórmula los simbolitos del $)

Comment: muchísimas gracias. Terminé usando BUSCARX, pero igualmente tu ejemplo fue de enorme ayuda. Al final terminé logrando lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias, de nuevo.